# can we convert models.Timefield to datetime in django

Tags: django

I have a `models.timefield` as

```
breakfast_start_time = models.TimeField(default=time(7, 30))
```

I want to add one more field automatically by overriding save method whose name is `breakfast_attendence_start_time` and value 15 minutes less than the user input in `breakfast_start_time`. How can I achieve that. `datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)` is not working with `models.Timefield` and I dont want to use `Datetimefield`. please help me with this code.

Is there any way to get hours and minutes seperately from `models.Timefield` this can also solve my problem.

Comment: How did you solve this in the end?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use timedelta on a datetime.time object.
You need to convert the time to a datetime, subtract the minutes and then convert it back to a time.

So in your save method you will have something like this:

```py
self.breakfast_attendence_start_time = (datetime.datetime.combine(  
    datetime.date(1, 1, 1),  
    self.breakfast_start_time
) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)).time()
```

Comment: Thanks! the code is working but it is giving warning ```Unexpected type(s):(date,time) Possible types: (date,time)(date,time)```

Comment: Can you update the answer with the code you have now? Maybe try to add .to_python() in the combine method, so you would have self.breakfast_start_time.to_python()

Comment: now my code is ```breakfast_start_time = models.TimeField(default=time(7, 30))``` and ni save method  ```def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.breakfast_attendence_start_time = (datetime.combine(
            date(1, 1, 1),
            self.breakfast_start_time
        ) - timedelta(minutes=15)).time()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)```

Comment: It is showing that .to_python needs a parameter. Should I write .to_python(datetime)?